# ‘Web App Library’ folder missing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, mysql-connector

In my dynamic web page under Libraries, I’m missing ‘Web App Library’. I tried right clicking on my project -> java build path -> removed ‘Web App Libraries’ -> add library ‘Web App Libraries’, but nothing shows under the library.

The ‘Web App Libraries’ will show in the Java build path.['Java Build Path'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtL7z.png)
but not under the Libary folder. [image01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzmYc.png)

I am trying to set up mysql-connector-java in WEB-INF / lib. Like this [image02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv4uh.png). This is also the correct build path I am trying to do [image03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vXn7.png).

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the Libraries under the library folder by yourself. Try drag drop or Add JAR/Folder option.